# Ruby iterate over a variable unless it is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I would like a clean way in .html.erb to loop through a variable ONLY if the variable is not nil.

I would like the following to execute but not if @family is nil.

```
<% @family.children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
    // HTML HERE
<% end %>
```

I am trying to avoid doing something like this

```
<% if @family %>
   <% @family.children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
       // HTML HERE
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And especially trying to avoid needing

```
<% if @family && @family.children %>
      <% @family.children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
          // HTML HERE
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about `@family && @family.children && @family.children.each.with_index(1)...`?

Comment: Can you try this `<% @family.try(:children).each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>` ?

Comment: @Pavan: this will end up with undefined method `each` for nil:NilClass

Comment: The object containing the collection you're trying to iterate seems to be `nil`, not the collection itself.

Comment: I am trying to defend against either being nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution can be misleading but Ruby's syntax allows you to do so:

```
<% @family.children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
    // HTML HERE
<% end unless @family.blank? %>
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I only use this solution for simple statements like testing the presence of an object (like in your case). **I do not recommend this solution for a more complex logic** because a third party would not know that the condition is at the end of the block.

---

Another one:

```
<% (@family.try(:children) || []).each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>

# mu-is-too-short's (brilliant) suggestion:
<% @family.try(:children).to_a.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
```

If `@family` is `nil`, the `try(:children)` won't raise an error but will return `nil`, then `nil || []` returns the empty array which "you can loop on it" (loop on it zero times actually).

Comment: I was wondering why my suggestion returns `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`. Your explanation clears my doubt.Thanks :)

Comment: This is clean and concise, but not as human readable. For a third party coming in looking at your code I would have no idea that the condition was at the **end** of the HTML block.

Comment: Why not `@family.try(:children).to_a`?

Comment: @muistooshort because I've never thought about it! brilliant ;)

Comment: @MikeSlutsky that is why I have added a small piece of text describing why I don't really like to use it except in these **very simple condition testing**

Comment: The various `to_X` methods are my usual ways to ignore `nil`s.

Comment: Thank you @mryoshiji, although it is misleading to use the unless at the end of the statement, I believe that is the solution I need.

Comment: You're welcome @MicFin. Yes it can be misleading, but here in your case it is very simple to guess what's going on. This is why I suggested this, I would not recommed using this with a way more complex logic

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), something like:

```
class NullFamily
  def children
    []
  end
end
```

In your controller:

```
@family = some_finder || NullFamily.new
```

Or you could pass a separate variable `@children`:

```
@family = some_finder
@children = @family.try(:children).to_a
```

And change your loop to:

```
<% @children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
    // HTML HERE
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Anthony indeed, awesome talk. I could watch it over and over again :-)

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
<% @family && @family.children.each.with_index(1) do |family_member, index| %>
    // HTML HERE
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need `@family && @family.children @family.children.each...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, presumably, if `@family` exists, it has children.

Comment: @Sergio, I was going by the OP's `if @family && @family.children`. For all I know a childless couple may have `@family.children #=> nil` rather than `@family.children #=> []` (though the latter seems a better design).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yeah, I got that. Somehow I got the impression that `children` is guaranteed to be non-empty. I must be wrong.

Comment: @Sergio, an empty array would be OK.

Comment: This is also a very nice solution

Comment: @CarySwoveland: by "non-empty" I actually meant "non-nil". Someone's tired. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have this in your controller?

```
@family ||= []
```

Comment: `[]` does not respond to `children`

Answer (score 0):

You can use if @family.present? or the opposite as unless @family.blank?